# Jquery chosen deletes options after "chosen:updated"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I use chosen plugin and 2 buttons for select value in different ways.
Here is html markup:

```
<div class="navigator-buttons-container common-scale-tool-shadow">
            <div class="scale-tool-buttons" id="zoomButtonDecr" style="border-left: 1px solid rgba(110,110,110,0.6);">
                <div class="scale-tool-minus-button"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 80px;" id="zoomContainer">
                <select class="scale-value-field chosen" id="zoomDropdown" tabindex="-1" data-placeholder="100%" style="width: 80px">
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="1.5">150%</option>
                    <option value="1.25">125%</option>
                    <option value="1">100%</option>
                    <option value="0.75">75%</option>
                    <option value="0.5">50%</option>
                    <option value="0.25">25%</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="scale-tool-buttons" id="zoomButtonIncr" style="border-right: 1px solid rgba(110,110,110,0.6);">
                <div class="scale-tool-plus-button"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I use this js function for updating dropdown default field text:

```
onZoomButtonIncrClick: function () {

        ... Some actions ...

        this.$el.find("#zoomDropdown").attr('data-placeholder', (self.currentZoom * 100) + '%');
        this.$el.find("#zoomDropdown").trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
```

But after updating dropdown loses all options.

What I make wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Chosen plugin to [1.0.0](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/) version.